# How can I make elements in one row for small screen?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I hav this two elements:

```
  <span>ddd:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="ui-state-disabled" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input" value="">
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="layerProperty">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1 id="layers property"></h1>
        <a href="#mapPage" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="vectorLayerProperties" style="display: none;">
            <fieldset style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
                <legend>data1</legend>
                <div class="ui-content">
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="ui-state-disabled" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input" value="">

                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="ui-state-disabled" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput2" placeholder="Text input" value="">

                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <select class="ui-state-disabled" name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
                                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
                            </select>

                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <select class="ui-state-disabled" name="select-native-1" id="select-native-2">
                                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <input type="Button" data-inline="true" value="Edit" onclick="editLayerProperty()">
                        <input type="Button" data-inline="true" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="vectorLayerslist"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside element with `id=vectorLayerProperties`   I have span element and textbox which I want to make in single line.

How can I make them in one row for screen with size 250px width?

Comment: Wrap them in a div and set display: inline-flex

Comment: They display on one line by default. Do you want them each on their own row?

Answer (score 1):

use media [queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and display block like the example, to reproduce it you will have to resize your browser window to 250px..

---

**UPDATE**

Wrap your span and input, inside div, a div has display block by default....

```css
@media (max-width: 250px) {
  .span,.input {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="span">ddd:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="input ui-state-disabled" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input" value="">
                            
                            
<div data-role="page" id="layerProperty">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1 id="layers property"></h1>
        <a href="#mapPage" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="vectorLayerProperties" >
            <fieldset style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
                <legend>data1</legend>
                <div class="ui-content">
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="ui-state-disabled" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput1" placeholder="Text input" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="ui-state-disabled" name="textinput-hide" id="textinput2" placeholder="Text input" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <select class="ui-state-disabled" name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
                                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                         <div>
                            <span>ddd:</span>
                            <select class="ui-state-disabled" name="select-native-1" id="select-native-2">
                                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
                            </select>
                            
                        </div>

                        <input type="Button" data-inline="true" value="Edit" onclick="editLayerProperty()">
                        <input type="Button" data-inline="true" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="vectorLayerslist"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Renzo, thanks for post.I tryed you solution but I can't make it work.Please see my update.